# Unequal and Compile

Tags: compile

```
(*can compiled*)
Compile[{}, Table[Boole[a == b == c], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"][]

(*can compiled*)
Compile[{}, Table[Boole[a != b != c], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}]][]

(*can't compiled*)
Compile[{}, Table[Boole[a != b != c], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}],
  CompilationTarget -> "C"][]
```

[image]

Why doesn't the third snippet code compile when I set CompilationTarget -> "C"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm it with *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and Linux. It seems that double inequalities is not yet implemented for `CompilationTarget -> "C"`.

You can manually expand `a != b != c` to `b != a && c != a && c != b`.

`LogicalExpand` can also be helpful

```
With[{neq = LogicalExpand[a != b != c]}, 
 Compile[{}, Table[Boole[neq], {a, 3}, {b, 3}, {c, 3}], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C"]]
```

> *no errors*

Comment: Confirmed with 9.01 and Win8x64

Comment: `Label` is not implemented either: `Compile[{}, Label[1]; Goto[1], CompilationTarget -> "C"]`. Both of these should be considered bugs in the `CCompilerDriver\`` package, IMO.

Comment: Not implemented in version 10.1 either