# Regarding CompilationTarget->"C"

Tags: compile

Recently I have read some interesting things about `CompilationTarget->"C"` on SE, e.g. in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54459/11116 where @MichaelE2 mentioned that "*compilation to C and Listable do not always get along*". In this regard, I want to pose three questions:

1. What are other things that are incompatible with `CompilationTarget->"C"`?
2. According to this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34070/11116 "*double inequalities is not yet implemented for `CompilationTarget -> "C".`*" What are some other functions that fall in that category? Is there a way to get the list of implemented functions?
3. Are there some guidelines on when `CompilationTarget -> "C"` performs better than `CompilationTarget -> "WVM"`?

Comment: Linked: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions

Comment: @blochwave. Thanks for the link. However, that link only talks about the compilable functions, which does not imply seamless compatible among all options/functions. In this question, I want to explore the limitations of  `CompilationTarget -> "C"` only.

Comment: Indeed, there may be some ideas presented in a few of the answers that might help with the investigation.

Comment: If `CompilationTarget -> "C"` doesn't work the same as `CompilationTarget -> "MVM"` then it's a bug in the `CCodeGenerator\`` package because the C code is generated directly from the MVM bytecode. If `"RuntimeAttributes" -> Listable` crashes the kernel, that's a bug in the kernel or the runtime. So I think you won't get many (any?) useful answers here, and should just report the bugs to WRI as you find them.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Point taken. However, I was looking for any known compatibility issues within/across the `compile` options and functions. For example what @MichaelE2 and @ybeltukov stated above are not mentioned in any document I came across. So I started this thread as a synthesis of known compatibility issues. I will report any bugs to WRI, but I think it is worth aggregating known issues till they are fixed by WRI.